# Locate all references to @deprecated code

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I want to get two lists of (file:lineNumber) about deprecated code:

1. Position of code with the JSDoc tag **@deprecated**
2. Code references to **@deprecated** code

If a tool for it does not exist yet, I would be OK with some guidance about how to implement that by myself.

For Point (1) some Javascript parser with knowledge of JSDoc marks should be enough. Maybe it could be done with something that just extracts JSDoc

Point(2) however seems out of the scope what plain Javascript can achieve. Typescript should be able to do this perfectly, but last time I checked, dealing with the AST and/or language server is is much harder (less documented).